# How can I detect a button press on a webcam?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webcam

I need to know when a button was pressed on my webcam but have no idea how to test for that particular input

I am working inside of the Unity games engine and can detect my webcam and show the video just fine and if I click on a button in the GUI then capturing the video is simple as pie... but Unity has no "Webcam button" input detect so I turned to Google and found the [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html) library that seems to have some sort of button catch that I can use to trigger an event.

Unfortunately, their demo was made for WinForms and it seems there is some magic happening in the background to detect the button press cause I don't see them scanning for any input anywhere in the code.

In addition, using the System.Windows.Forms DLL inside of Unity is not supported so that (my only current working example) cannot be ported to Unity.

This did show me that my webcam button CAN be detected, though, so now I just need to know "How do I scan for that?"

All I want is to know in my app is "A button was just pressed on your webcam". that is all. Unity natively has no such function so I am willing to import other DLLs if need be in order to get the job done... but I have no idea which DLL(s) those may be or how to scan for that button press.

Can anyone please give me some advice on how to scan for a button press on a webcam, please?

Comment: Hello, Can you show some code? Or What have you tried?

Comment: I'm curious what is your "button" meaning? Is is a picture/image in front of camera and you want to detect if it is pressed or not via camera too?

Comment: @TấnNguyên: I think "button on the webcam" is pretty clear, and does not mean a button with the webcam pointing at it.

Comment: I tried looping across all inputs that Unity provides but they focus on KB, Mouse and GamePads and don't have any support for webcam buttons. The AForgeNet.com library has a demo that works perfectly but I can't find any code in there that scans for input so I am thinking WinForms itself is taking care of scanning for input. As for the meaning of "button" I mean a physical button on my webcam. I want to let my application know when the physical button on the webcam was pressed but I have no idea how to do that. Some sites say "It's not possible" but the AForge demo works perfectly, but... how?

Comment: well does your webcam provide some sort of API for accessing this button input? and could you add some links to the resources you have looked at? As it is is your question is impossible to solve for us

Comment: Hi @derHugo  The lib that actually WORKS (but as a WebForm app) is here:[link](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html) AForgeNet.com. Specifically the "Snapshot Maker" demo. My webcams do NOT offer any sort of API but this demo detects the input equally well on the 10 EUR no-brand webcam as well as the high end 1000 EUR camera (Neither has a specific API) so it seems to be universal somehow. That is what surprises me. No custom APIs and yet it just works. It should work with any webcam you have laying around as long as it's one with a button (of course :P) so feel free to test it...

Comment: P.s. To everyone looking into this so far: Thank you! :)

Comment: @JansenSensei in the docs it states that `a snapshot will be provided through AForge.Video.DirectShow.VideoCaptureDevice.SnapshotFrame event.` that's why they don't need to additionally check the input. In the `"Snapshot Maker"` they add a callback to it in `connectButton_click`: `videoDevice.SnapshotFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler( videoDevice_SnapshotFrame );` it is not actually the button input they catch

Comment: @derHugo Yeah, I noticed that/it got pointed out to me recently. So it seems that "How to detect the shutter button being pressed" will remain a mystery but at least using their lib they are doing that work FOR me and as long as I **_stick_** to using their lib I can "_do that check_" by just subscribing to that event rather than manually actually writing the code that looks for the button being pressed. I am now trying to see if I can get that working. I think that is the way to go. No escaping using the AForge library it seems. Meh, as long as it works I suppose.Right? :) Thank you

Comment: P.s. to avoid ambiguity, you said "It's not actually the button input they catch" but that statement is incorrect. Yes, they send out an event when the shutter press was detected but it **DOES** actually detect the shutter being pressed. They actually say this in the docs which is why I started saying "_shutter_" rather than "_webcam button_" since that is what they call it in the docs. I was interested in knowing HOW (I can/they do) detect the shutter being pressed but I guess just letting them get on with it and do it for me is perfectly acceptable enough :) Makes life easier for everyone :)